# LoaderManager onLoadFinished is called but RecyclerView is not refreshed

Tags: android, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I have a ContentProvider which manages a sqlite database. In the query() method of the ContentProvider I registered notifications as you should:

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

And if an entry is inserted I notify all observers from the insert() method in the ContentProvider with this call:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
```

The RecyclerView is in a fragment and the fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks to allow reaction on changes.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loader, Bundle bundle) {
    switch (loader) {
        case URL_LOADER:
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), DataProvider.PERSONS_URI, 
                                    null, null, null, null);

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    this.mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    this.mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

These are my LoaderCallbacks. If I insert a element via ContentResolver onLoadFinished gets called, but the UI is not updated. When I restart the app the entries are visible. The adapter which is needed to support cursors for RecyclerView is based on this gist. https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b

Comment: Did you debug swapCursor method?

Comment: Yes, I stepped through it after the notification of an inserted element called onLoadFinished and it did correctly swap the cursor, set the new one and return the old one.

Comment: Oh wait, I looked over my code one more time I must have missed one line which does call notifyDataSetChanged(); in the swapCursor. I will fix this. Thanks for the hint!